# "Invalid column name" when "Specify database fields" in table output is unchecked in pentaho PDI V7

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to insert data to SQL database. I have all the columns in the same order as the data flow. But I'm getting this "Invalid column name name_of_the_actual_data_column" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column order won't matter, but exact column names will.  Your SQL implementation probably isn't picky enough to require *case-sensitive* matches, but spaces and punctuation *will* matter.  With `Specify database fields` *unchecked*, all field names **MUST** exist as columns in the target table.

I've found a good way to troubleshoot SQL inserts is to put a `Select` step before the `Table output` and make sure that you're really only getting the columns you want to insert.

You can also right-click on the `Table output` step and choose `Input fields...` to see the column metadata being passed into the step.